# Angular Material CSS console warnings

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, firefox-developer-tools

I just installed Angular Material to my new project and noticed that it throws over a hundred warnings in the Firefox console, mostly dropped declarations. Besided this, no errors at all. I tried this with a local file and a CDN link and the result is the same. Does anybody know what causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for you so you can avoid using those declaration as they have planned to implement the new or changed name. I got those warning all the time and it means as long i stick to the same version i could forget about those warnings but if i upgrade i can be in trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.